# New Master Page - Changes Not Reflected as Site Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, master-page, publishing-site, system-master-page

I'm facing a perplexing issue with making my changes from a master page reflect on the front-end.

Strangely, if I enable my new master page **on System Master Page** it works, however when I enable it on **Site Master Page** changes only appear on the SP 404 page, not any other pages. Clearly, I'm missing something.

I am Using SharePoint Designer 2013. Also, I have Checked In and Published the changes.

I have read through most other duplicates relating to this question and I have tried all proposed answers and am now seeking further guidance.

My SP site is a **Publishing Site**, with a Welcome Page set.

Thanks

Comment: How did you identified that it is applied only on 404 Page?
you manually accessed the page or you accessed your site and you landed on 404 page?

Comment: Hi, I purposely looked at different pages to check - to my surprise finding the Master Page working on only that.

Comment: So the Home Page of your site has the default Master Page. and you are not getting any error?

Comment: It appears so, I've set the Master Page within Site Master Page Settings - am I missing something obvious?!

Comment: Could not understand your last comment. Can you add the screen shots so we can get some more details.

Comment: Sorry, yes - the homepage appears to be the default master page. I'm confused why that would be as I have it set to my new master page.